# MiKTeX package sets

Tags: packages, miktex, repositories

I see that MiKTeX has 3 package sets:

```
--package-set=SET
Set the package set (one of: essential, basic, complete).
```

However I could not find a list of what is included with these. I tried this
with no luck:

```
$ miktexsetup --print-info-only download
initializing setup service...
setup task: download
local package repository: "D:\Desktop\MiKTeX Download Files"
package set: complete
remote package repository: http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/
win32/miktex/tm/packages/
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is not very important. You set your MikTeX-installation to "download missing packages automatically" and you are fine. Sometimes you have to compile documents several times, because on every run another package is missing until finally all of them are downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command instead, and just cancel after few seconds:

```
$ miktexsetup --verbose download
initializing setup service...
starting downloader...
starting download...
repository: https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
download directory: "D:\Desktop\MiKTeX Download Files"
visiting repository https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/
packages/...
repository type: remote package repository
loading package repository manifest...
downloading https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
```

The last line is a link to an archive, containing the manifest file `mpm.ini`.
Here is a section:

```
[12many]
CabMD5=78e41f641a1a0b49c79e94b6421e1988
CabSize=383872
Level=L
MD5=1c74ba5c710b75403c69a7446690c919
TimePackaged=1310767635
Type=TarLzma
Version=0.3
```

The important part is `Level=L`. Full list:

```
$ grep Level mpm.ini | sort | uniq -c
3555 Level=L
  83 Level=M
 193 Level=S
  62 Level=T
```

This was confusing to me, as the help lists 3 levels, not 4. So what is the last
level? I found the answer here:

```
MIKTEX_ASSERT(
PackageLevel::None < PackageLevel::Essential
&& PackageLevel::Essential < PackageLevel::Basic
&& PackageLevel::Basic < PackageLevel::Advanced
&& PackageLevel::Advanced < PackageLevel::Complete);
```

https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/blob/a4a7a810/Libraries/MiKTeX/PackageManager/PackageInstallerImpl.cpp#L97-L101

after some testing, this is my finding:

```
Level=S (small): essential
Level=M (medium): basic
Level=L (large): advanced
Level=T (total): complete
```